# Salesforce OEM Edition/License

Tags: editions

I need to understand the fine details, possibilities and pricing of Salesforce OEM model. I can't find an official link about this on salesforce and google, only link available is this 2008 pdf : http://www.developerforce.com/tdf/2008/april/Force_ISV_Partner.pdf

Please share any good post/article on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could find the OEM Licence model is charged $25 / user / month

everything OEM partners need to build and deliver on-demand applications:

common user interface, and a single security and data sharing model;
AppExchange API, the AppExchange Database and AppExchange Builder for customization and integration;
5 custom tabs;
50 custom objects;
salesforce.com's service delivery platform, setting the standard for security, reliability and transparency.

I found Couple of Links and thought it might help

Salesforce Press Release : http://shivd.me/OJvxyo

A LinkedIn Post :          http://shivd.me/OJuDBS

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced a variety of ISV OEM license models as a Salesforce customer, so I think the actual license type is negotiable based on a number factors:

- Industry/vertical market size
- Opportunity potential
- Dependency on CRM standard objects vs 100% Force.com platform app
- Potential for OEM to augment existing license types and features

The best outcome for an ISV using the OEM license is to have Salesforce actively partnered and selling your app.

Maybe start by clicking on the "Join" link here and you should get routed to an industry expert
http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/

You can also direct message me with details and I will attempt to make the most relavent introduction.