# What does OEM stands for?

Tags: licenses, oem

I was trying to find out difference about ISV and OEM licencing.

Found many useful resources but did not get **what OEM stands for**?

Here are links which i have already gone through:

[Salesforce OEM license restrictions for end users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/salesforce-oem-license-restrictions-for-end-users/28898#28898)

[Salesforce OEM Edition/License](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/salesforce-oem-edition-license)

Comment: 6 upvotes for a question that requires 4 keystrokes in google?

Comment: Those google results gotta come from somewhere...might as well be us!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OEM is an abbreviation for [Original Equipment Manufacturer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_equipment_manufacturer):

> An original equipment manufacturer, or OEM, manufactures products or
>   components that are purchased by another company and retailed under
>   that purchasing company's brand name. OEM refers to the company that
>   originally manufactured the product. When referring to automotive
>   parts, OEM designates a replacement part made by the manufacturer of
>   the original part.

In Salesforce, going the OEM route allows you to sell Salesforce licenses directly to **your** customers. It does not require them to already be a Salesforce customer. For instance, say you are building some new advertising tool for tracking customers and their ads. This type of system is going to be beneficial to a large group of people, not only Salesforce's customers. By going OEM, you can sell just your app to your customers (in the bundle you would include the required Salesforce licenses). This allows app builders to sell to anyone.

In contrast, ISV customers can only sell to existing Salesforce customers. This is ideal for an app that may not be relevant to a larger market but specifically targets Salesforce customers, like a Chatter app for instance.

---

Deciding to go ISV or OEM is a [big decision that has implications](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16659/605). If you are thinking of building an app, work with your partner rep to determine which is better for you. Do [your research first](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/overview) so you understand what you are getting into.